# Is Prophet Muhammed (PBUH) part of the family of Ibrahim (PBUH)?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, history, prophet-ibrahim

One of my Christian friend and I were discussing about Islam and Christianity. I am not well versed with Prophets and their history. He told me that in the Bible, it is said that the descendants of Ismail (PBUH), first son of Ibrahim (PBUH), will become a great generation and will deviate from the truth. Hence he believes, we are following a different version of Christianity as per the Bible.

He did not tell me the bible verse. May be it is part of the new testament. But I initially thought, Muhammed (PBUH) was not related by blood with other prophets. I did some research and tumbled on [this](http://www.whyislam.org/common-ground/family-tree-of-prophets/). There are lots of comments there. Some say it is false. Some say it is true. Can any scholar shed some light on this matter?

Comment: IT is well known that Muhammad (pbuh) is a descendent of Isma'il (pbuh) son of Ibrahim (pbuh), but there are differences about the linaeage between Isma'il and 'Adnan.

Comment: @Medi1Saif So is the family tree, shown in the link correct?

Comment: Well from Muhammad to 'Adnan without any doubt from 'Adnan to Isma'il Allah knows best!

Answer (score 2):

Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ) is a descendant of Abraham (عليه السلام). This is evident from the Quran:

> ملة **أبيكم** إبراهيم
>
> [It is] the religion of **your** **father**, Abraham
>
> <sup>— [Quran 22:78](https://quran.com/22/78?translations=20)</sup>

It is also corroborated elsewhere in the Quran, such as:

> [Quran 2:127-129](https://quran.com/2/127-129) And [mention] when **Abraham was raising the foundations
> of the House** and [with him] **Ishmael,** [saying], "Our Lord, accept
> [this] from us. Indeed You are the Hearing, the Knowing. Our Lord, and
> make us Muslims [in submission] to You **and from our descendants a
> Muslim nation** [in submission] to You. And show us our rites and accept
> our repentance. Indeed, You are the Accepting of repentance, the
> Merciful. Our Lord, and **send among them a messenger from themselves**
> who will recite to them Your verses and teach them the Book and wisdom
> and purify them. Indeed, You are the Exalted in Might, the Wise."
>
> [Quran 14:37](https://quran.com/14/37) Our Lord, I have settled **some of my descendants**
> in an uncultivated **valley near Your sacred House**, our Lord, that
> they may establish prayer. So make hearts among the people incline
> toward them and provide for them from the fruits that they might be
> grateful.

The above verses establish that the descendants of Ishmael  (عليه السلام) settled around the House (Kaabah) and that a Messenger would be raised from among them who would bring them a Scripture. The Messenger that Abraham  (عليه السلام) prayed for in 2:129 refers to the Prophet Muhammad  (ﷺ) .

> أَنَا دَعْوَةُ أَبِي إِبْرَاهِيمَ
>
> I am the supplication of my father Abraham
>
> <sup>— [Saheeh Ibn Hibban](https://shamela.ws/book/1729/9343)</sup>

---

There are several Hadith where the Prophet claimed descent from Abraham  (عليه السلام), among them:

> قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ "‏ إِنَّ اللَّهَ اصْطَفَى
> مِنْ وَلَدِ إِبْرَاهِيمَ إِسْمَاعِيلَ وَاصْطَفَى مِنْ وَلَدِ
> إِسْمَاعِيلَ بَنِي كِنَانَةَ وَاصْطَفَى مِنْ بَنِي كِنَانَةَ قُرَيْشًا
> وَاصْطَفَى مِنْ قُرَيْشٍ بَنِي هَاشِمٍ وَاصْطَفَانِي مِنْ بَنِي
> هَاشِمٍ
>
> The Messenger of Allah said: Allah chose from the **Children of Abraham**:
> Ishmael. And chose from the children of Ishmael: Bani Kananah, and
> from the Bani Kananah He chose the Quraysh, and from the Quraysh He
> chose Bani Hashim, and **He chose me from the Bani Hashim**.
>
> <sub>— [Jami Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/urn/734660) كتاب المناقب ( Book of virtues )</sub>

> رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم يَقُولُ ‏ "‏ إِنَّ اللَّهَ اصْطَفَى
> كِنَانَةَ مِنْ وَلَدِ إِسْمَاعِيلَ وَاصْطَفَى قُرَيْشًا مِنْ كِنَانَةَ
> وَاصْطَفَى مِنْ قُرَيْشٍ بَنِي هَاشِمٍ وَاصْطَفَانِي مِنْ بَنِي
> هَاشِمٍ ‏"
>
> The Messenger of Allah said: Verily Allah granted eminence to Kinana
> from amongst the **descendants of Ishmael**, and he granted eminence to
> the Quraish amongst Kinana, and he granted eminence to Banu Hashim
> amongst the Quraish, and **he granted me eminence from the tribe of
> Banu Hashim**.
>
> <sub>— [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/43/1)  كتاب الفضائل  ( Book of virtues )</sub>

Comment: Could you explain further how the verses of the quran **prove** that Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ) is a descendant of Abraham?

Comment: I am not denying that interpretation, I just thought it might need some further explanation, because by just reading the verses it is hard to draw that conclusion. Maybe you could add some [tafsir](http://altafasir.com/al-quran/surat/2/al-baqarah/129/al-tabari) of that verses "وهذه دعوة إبراهيـم وإسماعيـل لنبـينا مـحمد صلى الله عليه وسلم خاصة"